# App crashes on button Click Action iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have created a button and added its action at runtime. The entire view is created at runtime.
Calling the action `saveUserProfileSetting` on click crashes the app `"NSInvalidArgument: Unrecornized selector sent to a instance` . It was working okay when the code was present in 
 another class. I tried to create an new class for it and it crashes.

```
@interface LASplashViewer : NSObject

        +(void) showSplashScreen;
        +(void) dismissSplashScreen;

        @end

    (void) showSplashScreen
    {
        UIView *mainScreen = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window];

        UIView *windowBlocker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:mainScreen.frame];
        windowBlocker.tag = 999;
        windowBlocker.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIButton *saveButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 430, 420, 30)];
        [saveButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [saveButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveUserProfileSetting) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 200, 450, 480)];

        imageView.layer.cornerRadius=10;
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [windowBlocker addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView addSubview:saveButton];
     imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true;

        [mainScreen addSubview:windowBlocker];
    }

    -(void) saveUserProfileSetting
    {
        // TODO: if validation is successful save the below data. and dismiss the splash screen.
        NSUserDefaults *userSettings = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];

        [userSettings setObject:fullName.text forKey:@"name_pref"];
        NSLog(@"%@fullname" , fullName);
        [userSettings setObject:jobTitle.text forKey:@"title_pref"];
        [userSettings setObject:streetName.text forKey:@"street_name_pref"];
        [userSettings setObject:suburbs.text forKey:@"suburb_pref"];
        [userSettings setObject:postCode.text forKey:@"postcode_pref"];
        [userSettings setObject:phoneNum.text forKey:@"phone_no_pref"];
        [userSettings setObject:fax.text forKey:@"fax_pref"];
        [userSettings setObject:mobileNumber.text forKey:@"mobile_no_pref"];
        [userSettings setObject:email.text forKey:@"email_pref"];
        [userSettings synchronize];
    }
```

Call to the method is Show is in another
 class - // HomeViewController.

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isFirstLaunch"])
    {
        // app already launched
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"isFirstLaunch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        // call this method only for the first load.
        //[self performSelector:@selector() withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
        [self performSelector:@selector(saveProfile) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.5];
        }
}
-(void) saveProfile
{
    [LASplashViewer showSplashScreen];
}
```

**log :**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[LASplashViewer saveUserProfileSetting]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2a4dc'

please guide me. Thanks

Comment: where have u defined saveProfile method?

Comment: `[self performSelector:@selector(saveProfile) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.5];` I think your problem somewhere here

Comment: plese have a look in my latest edit.

Comment: can you put the full crash log. there will be a reason

Comment: NSInvalidArgument: Unrecornized selector sent to a instance there should be method name mentioned here?

Comment: where you are calling this [LASplashViewer saveUserProfileSetting]?

Comment: I suspect you dont have a class method named `saveUserProfileSetting`. the method i can see with same name is an instance mehtod

Comment: its the action added at runtime and will be called when button is clicked.

Comment: As many have already send please provide the error that you are getting.

Comment: According to crash log you are calling `saveUserProfileSetting` by class name `[LASplashViewer saveUserProfileSetting];` while you defined it as object method. Call it by  LASplashViewer's object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[LASplashViewer saveUserProfileSetting]` is crashing because it is not a static function. Make your function as

1) `+ (void)saveUserProfileSetting { }`

2) Or call as

```
LASplashViewer *viewer = [[LASplashViewer alloc] init];
[viewer saveUserProfileSetting];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you call instance selector from class method

`LASplashViewer` have class method `showSplashScreen` where you call instance method `saveUserProfileSetting`

to solve problem try make `saveUserProfileSetting` also class method (replace `-` to `+`)

Answer (score 0):

`+(void) showSplashScreen;` is a class method,  from which you are setting action for the button

```
[saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveUserProfileSetting) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Here the target is `self`. Inside a class method `self` refers to its own `Class` not to the instance. So here the target of the method is `LASplashViewer` not its instance. Your button expects a class method like `+(void)saveUserProfileSetting`. It is not finding a class method with such name. So its crashing. I hope you understood root cause.

Solution is make method as a class method

```
+ (void)saveUserProfileSetting
```